# Model averaging when linear and quadratic effects are modeled in a global model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, aic, beta-distribution

I am trying to derived estimates of model-averaged parameter effects on a fairly complicated set of models using an information-theoretic approach. I have several models that investigate continuous and categorical variables, interactions of these variables, and I have a global model which includes all of these variables and interactions. My question is, when I am model averaging, I read that the beta estimates for the slope of the effect of a quadratic term are represented by x+x^2. But, I also have a linear model of this same variable (e.g., x=linear time and x+x^2 = quadratic time).

My first question is: Do I use both beta estimates for the quadratic model (e.g., x and x^) as part of calculating my model-averaged estimate?

Second question is: In my global model, the way I've set up my models (which I assume must be incorrect) I only have a beta estimate for x and x^2 I assume these are to be interpreted as the quadratic term x+x^2). Should I somehow be able to have an extra parameter in the global model, so that I have two estimates for x? An x to represent the linear term by itself, and a different estimate for x that is part of the x+x^2? Thanks for any help you can give to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just averaging model fits/predictions, it won't matter, but when you say "*the quadratic term*" it implies you're interested in averaging parameter estimates, in which case you should be dealing with the actual term with an $x^2$ in it, rather than the combination of linear and quadratic.

*However*, in that case, it would be best to work with orthogonal polynomials, because then the presence of higher order terms doesn't impact the lower order estimates; you can average over the parameter estimates without their meaning changing.

Compare what happens without and then with orthogonal polynomials:

First, fitting linear and then linear+quadratic:

```
> lm(dist~speed,cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed  
    -17.579        3.932  

> lm(dist~speed+I(speed^2),cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed   I(speed^2)  
    2.47014      0.91329      0.09996
```

As you see, the coefficient of `speed` is substantively affected by the presence of the `speed^2` term. By comparison, when we use orthogonal polynomials, the fit is the same in both cases, but the coefficient of the linear term is the same in both models:

```
> lm(dist~poly(speed,1),cars)

Coefficients:
   (Intercept)  poly(speed, 1)  
         42.98          145.55  

> lm(dist~poly(speed,2),cars)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  poly(speed, 2)1  poly(speed, 2)2  
          42.98           145.55            23.00
```

In this situation, when a term is present in the model, its meaning is the same whether there are higher order terms or not; model averaging over parameters can be explicitly seen as shrinkage toward zero (since the averaged estimate will be a weighted average of 0, when it's absent, and the estimate, when it's in the model).